# how to set default camera, if the device have two camera in C#.net

Tags: c#, wpf

In my project i have two combobox that showing the list of available video devices and audio devices. i want to set a default video device to capture the image.

In my code

```
var vidDevices = EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Video);
var audDevices = EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Audio);
```

by default it shows "Screen Capture Source" but i want to show the list of available devices.

Comment: You're already retrieving the available audio and video devices as a list...
All you need to do is use the one marked as 'selected' in your combobox

Comment: sorry i cant get you @timothy please explain briefly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you have passed this line :

```
var vidDevices = EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Video);
```

`vidDevices` will contain en enumerable with all available devices in it.

In WPF, you can simply pass this into the combobox as an itemssource like this :

```
combobox.itemsSource = vidDevices;
```

Then, in order to get the one the user selected, take the `SelectionChanged` event of the combobox and do something like this :

```
var selectedDevice = comboBox.SelectedItem as EncoderDevice;
```

Comment: Ya thank you, Another thing i want is that how can we access & check the front and back camera of a Tab??

Comment: Since front cameras tend to have a lower resolution, you could probably tell them apart from that.